# need a .net collection which is similar to std::map

Tags: .net, collections

I need a .net collection which has the following features (similar to std::map):

1. Addition/Deletion is O(log n)
2. Search is O(log n)
3. Has a BinarySearch like method which returns the closest object (similar to `List<>`).
4. Can traverse objects in order starting from an arbitrary place.

`SortedDictionary<>` fulfills 1,2 but not 3,4.
`List<>` satisfies 3,4 but not 1,2.

What solutions can you suggest?

Comment: `List<>` does not provide built in BinarySearch, it do QuickSort

Comment: @sll you mean except for the [`BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh.aspx) method ;p

Comment: @Marc Gravell: wow great! Just wondering how I missed this method.... thanks!

Comment: I don't know of any such collection being built in. Guess you'll need a third party class.

Comment: You can traverse `SortedDictionary<>` in order starting at an arbitrary place using the `Skip()` extension method.  You just can't jump to that place via index (an implementation detail that only effects perf.  Is it actually important for your scenario?).  Why do you need `BinarySearch` if you can already search?  Do you need a comparison function that is different than the one used for #2?

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham `SortedDictionary` only lets you search for *existing* elements. And `Skip` is `O(n)`, I assume the OP wants logarithmic performance.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Oh, "closest object".  I didn't realize binary search did that (because I haven't used it).  Thanks for clarifying.  As for #4, I would also assume that, but the OP didn't specify `O(1)`, so I'd like them to challenge that somewhat ambiguous requirement or affirm it.  Basically, I'd suggest they try their algorithm without it and see if it really matters, or affirm that it is important for their algorithm.

Comment: I guess even if you can ignore #4, you can't implement binary search yourself without indexing, so you're going to need a custom container.